# Use dissolve tool on a polygon layer with attributes from a point layer. ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I'm trying to find a way to automatically merge polygons with others based on a max + minimum value of points in each polygon. So the small ones go together with other small ones and the bigger ones stays the same.
Basically I've made this far with a Buffer around each point Dissolve and Minimum bounding geometry to get the polygons like this (see link in comments for more precise) [image] Now I want to take this to the next level and make the smaller polygons to merge with other small polygons. I'm curious if it's possible to do all this with tools instead of drawing by hand which could be easy in this case but I've got other much larger maps. 
I want the result to look more like this (from Qgis and its drawn by hand)
[image]

Note that the lines has nothing to do with this it's all about the polygons around the points. I want about the same amount of points in each polygon.

One thought was to choose all polygons with < 50 points and make the process again in a new layer with larger buffer but it doesnt quite do the job.
(I hope this makes any sense to you, its hard to explain when I'm new to this)

Comment: I read your problem many times, but I still don't understand your problem. Please edit your question and add some information about what you tried so far and maybe an image of what your polygons should look like.

Comment: The tool you're looking for is Dissolve, though it doesn't have anything to do with points, only the attributes on polygons.

Comment: I dont really understand how to use dissolve when i dont have polygons overlapping or lining up with other polygons. If I make the polygons bigger it will just be one big polygon of everything. I want to tell the dissolve tool to stop when it has reached a certain number of points in a polygon and start a new one.

Comment: Then you need to focus the question on making the attribute changes to allow Dissolve to do its job.

Comment: This is how the first map was done: http://sv.tinypic.com/r/oud1sw/9

Answer (score 2):

Try use:

Aggregate Polygons (Cartography) - Combines polygons within a specified distance to each other into new polygons.

[ESRI help](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/ARCGISDESKTOP/10.0/HELP/index.html#/Aggregate_Polygons/00700000000s000000/)

Answer (score 2):

I think you could repeat the process for polygons that do not have a given point-density. This means for every polygon you already clustered you count the number of aggreagated points and relate this to the polygons area. If the density is lower then a given threshhold you repeat the aggregation you already did.

You may repaet this step with an increasing buffer-size until either all polygons have at least a given amount of points or after a given amount of iterations.